# Is there an app similar to superputty?

Tags: ssh

I'd be needing to connect to several AWS EC2 instances and putty works fine with the keys, but it's just one at a time. I also tried Remmina, however it keeps asking SSH private keyphrase what it shouldn't. Any other suggestion?

Comment: This belongs in the Software Recommendation SE, not in Ask Ubuntu, because this is asking for an opinion-based software recommendation, and not about an issue with Ubuntu. Please relocate this question.

Comment: @zwork the fact that it *also* is on topic on Software Recommendation does not mean it is off-topic here.

Comment: ", but it's just one at a time"? I have 9 putty screens open at the moment all to google instances each using a  ssh key. Why can't you?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yes, I agree with that, but my interpretation was that OP was looking for a new piece of software, and not support with Remmina. This post could definitely go either way.

Comment: As a Ubuntu user, I sort of assumed this was the forum to turn to if I get stuck on what software to use.  With regard to opinion based recommendations, though the definition of sameness may be a little loose what it comes to functionality, I am not asking for the "best" of something. I have a problem to solve, and replacement software may be one such solution.

In either case,  @zwork is probably right, Jacob, so how do I move this where? :) And thanks for chipping in.

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh copy the contents of your title/question, and head over to [Software Recommendation SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and ask it there (then delete this question).

Answer (score 0):

I use `ssh-agent` to load keys.  You can control the length of time the keys are active.

You can also use a private configuration file to specify the key and other settings for individual hosts.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to manage multiple simultaneous SSH connections and their associated shell sessions. For that job use the default SSH client `ssh` and your favourite terminal emulator/multiplexer (see [What terminal emulators are available for heavy terminal users?](/q/7605/175814) for suggestions).

If you want to avoid retyping the SSH key pass phrase for every new connection you should use a "key agent" like `ssh-agent` to keep a copy of once unlocked SSH keys in memory for later reuse.